# Is there a way to log and view application run time statistics in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, logging, statistics

I'm looking for a way to collect stats on what apps are launched when and for how long they're used on my Windows 7 PC. Is there a native tool for that? If there is not, what are the popular third-party tools?

Answer (score -1):

Windows performance monitor and Windows performance analyzer for native.

To do this, click on the start button in the bottom left corner, in the text field that says "search programs and files" type "performance monitor". As for knowing what to do, I'd suggest reading documentation as you will get more out of it than me explaining it. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) is a link.

Comment: What a vague answer. Might as well link cppreference and the entire win32 API docs.